# Firebase Hosting: Change default SSL to Norton SSL?

Tags: firebase, ssl, ssl-certificate, norton

Is it possible to change the default SSL Certificate on Firebase Hosting to use Norton SSL Certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSL certificates used by Firebase Hosting are not user-configurable, so this is not possible at present. I'd encourage you to file a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) so we can track the desired use case.

Comment: Will do. Thank you fast reply.